# Android app drawable images (icons) loose colors to white on some devices in Lollipop

Tags: android, xamarin, icons, png

When I am adding transparent png icons/images, their color schema changes to "monochrome white", i.e. all the colors but white change to white as on the image:
[image]

Most of devices were working well so far, it happens not often.

I am not sure if that's related to the image format, OS version or device, but probably someone already bumped into similar thing.

The images are added as AndroidResource as `drawable` and have different resolution versions. (I am using Xamarin Android, but not sure if that's related to the issue).

The issue is happening as when the image is added to widgetTab.Layout as `menu item` as just setting up `ImageView`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Once it's not the same behavior to all devices, there is a possibility of one of the *different resolution version* is broken... Have you checked it?

Comment: I've experienced some graphical issues with Android 5.0 (no more on the 5.1 - or the opposite, I can't remember now) version, but I simply ignored it. Deal with it didn't worth for me that time.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but a) I did check all the versions, and b) they were generated by Adobe XD automatically, which rather eliminates any such problems.